# handling side effects using Monad

Tags: scala, monads

In the below program I am not able to understand the thought process behind the implementation of map and flatMap. That's why I am not able to think about how to implement map and flatMap in case of different types of side effects, for example, print statement, etc.

Can someone please explain?

```
import java.util.UUID

object MonadSideEffectToPure extends App {

  case class User(id: UUID, email: String)
  case class Address(id: Int, city: String, country: String)
  case class Email(to: String, subject: String, body: String)

  def findUser(id: UUID): User = {
    //perform database operations and return user
    User(id, "test@gmail.com")
  }

  def getAddress(user: User): Address = {
    //perform database operation and return address
    Address(1, "haryana", "India")
  }

  def sendEmail(email: Email) = {
    //send an email using third party service
    println(s"email sent to ${email.to} ...")
  }

  //Create IO Monad
  class IO[A] private(block: => A) {
    def run : A = block
    def flatMap[B] (f:A => IO[B]): IO[B] = IO {f(run).run}
    def map[B] (f: A => B): IO[B] = flatMap(a => IO{f(a)})
  }

  object IO {
     def apply[A](block: => A): IO[A] = new IO(block)
  }

  val result: IO[Unit] = for {
    user <-  IO { findUser(UUID.randomUUID())}
    address <- IO {getAddress(user)}
    _ <- IO {sendEmail(Email(user.email, address.city + "News", "Good News"))}
  } yield()

  result.run
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? BTW, you rarely implement your own Monad, rather you use existing ones. So, even if implementing your own may be a good academic exercise, I would focus on first being able to understand it and latter implement it. Also, I would first implement **Option**, **Either**, **List**, **Reader** & **State** _(in that order)_ before going to **IO**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I mean to say how to write an implementation of flatMap and map. I understood that in the above scenario, flatMap should take a function which takes an input of type A and return IO[B], but when we say that it is equal to IO {f(run).run}, i do not understand. Same with map implementation.

Comment: Again, as I said, it is difficult to answer that. And the best is that you get to the answer yourself, but that would be easier if you start with simple. I would also recommend you reading **Scala with Cats** if you haven't and watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJGDHERh23x-9bxGrCbyX-tXJG99XczNC) play list about monads.

Comment: If you want to implement `IO`, it would be helpful to understand how things like `Eval` and/or `Free` work. In general your should understand that monad is an interface with a contracts, and how you will implement it will differ depending on  what is implementing that interface: container? asynchronicity? Passing state without a global variable? It will help if you use several of them and them implement simpler ones before you move to IO. Otherwise, you'll just write something without a feeling why it should be written this way and not the other.